# How to read size in bytes syntax in Play configuration (HOCON)?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, hocon

The Play documentation claims it supports declaring sizes in quantity prefixes (MB, MiB, GB, etc.) It doesn't however state how I'm supposed to read such values in code.

I have the following configuration value:

```
discavo.upload.image.maxSize = 2 MiB
```

and I tried loading it as

```
current.configuration.getInt("discavo.upload.image.maxSize").get
```

but got the following error:

```
Configuration error[conf/application.conf: 129: discavo.upload.image.maxSize has type STRING rather than NUMBER]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you should use `getBytes` instead of `getInt`, which returns an `Option[Long]`:

```
current.configuration.getBytes("discavo.upload.image.maxSize").get.toInt
```

Answer (score 0):

in the conf, just write as following:

```
discavo.upload.image.maxSize = 2
```

instead of your code:

```
discavo.upload.image.maxSize = 2 MiB
```

the reason is that when you get the "discavo.upload.image.maxSize", you get '2 MiB' including number '2' and its unit 'MiB' that the method 'toInt' can convert it to a number.

Good luck with you

Comment: I'm not expecting to get `2`, but `2097152`, i.e. `2^20`, which the unit correctly represents.